# Change of temperature in liquid when it is pressurized fast to high pressure

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas

Here's one question I've been thinking for some time: Let's assume that certain volume of water (or any other normal liquid, I'm just thinking how these kind of things should be calculated) is pressurized very fast to high pressures, let's say a few thousand bars. In such a high pressures even water starts to be compressible. At least in my mind water should have some (maybe quite small) temperature raise. I would be interested how much this raise would be? Is it, let's say 0.01, 0.1, 1 or 10C? I think ideal gas law "pV=nRT" type of equations are no good in this case? How would you calculate such a thing?

Best regards,

-dr_mushroom

Answer (score 0):

Can throw out the ideal gas law as it is not a gas

You do work on the system and from conservation of energy that work is in the system.  It will result in a temperature increase.  You calculate it based on the work performed on the system.

Speed of the work is not a factor.  Assume the walls are insulated (adiabatic).

Since a liquid is very incompressible it is not possible to do much work on the system.   You could take it to 1000 psi and it would be a very small temperature change.

Gas is different. If you pump air into a tank air temperature in the tank will increase.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Frisbee! Yep, in this case pressure raise is instantaneous and/or walls would be insulated. So, no heat transfer is done to environment. It is rather suprising that this temperature raise in adiabatic process is not hard to calculate for ideal gas (even Wiki has example of that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process) but my problem seems to lie in fact that I would be interested to do the same calculation (even rougly) for liquid

Comment: Then do that same calculation for a liquid.  You just need the P verses V for the the liquid.

Comment: If you look at an experimentally determined [phase diagram](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/phaseeqia/phasediags.html) for [water](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/08/Phase_diagram_of_water.svg/700px-Phase_diagram_of_water.svg.png), you can see the effects of changing pressure and temperature.

Comment: @Ernie Those phase diagrams are of no benefit to this problem.  Need volume (density) for a liquid in the liquid phase.

Comment: Thanks Ernie anyway! Just looking for pV-diagram for liquid water (or any liquid), seems quite hard to find..

Comment: http://www.windows2universe.org/earth/Water/density.html

Comment: Somehow missed Frisbees comment. Problem is now solved I think: I found that  I used relation between force F=pA=kx,  potential energy

Comment: If that is the answer then you can indicate so with a check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow missed Frisbees comment, thanks for that! I think problem is now solved: I found bulk modulus of water. Then I used relation between force F=pA=kx, (-> x=pA/k), put them to potential energy equation E=1/2kx^2 and assumed that all stored potential energy goes for heating of liquid. Í was asking how much temperature raises when high pressure is added. According to calculation, for example 5000Bar pressure increase rises temperature of water few degrees.

Comment: So you used my answer and my comment to get comprehensibility of water but post it as your answer.  1/2kx^2 is work.

Comment: Frisbee: Apologies if that offended you. I used whole conversation history of this thread in my answer and I did not mention it. Maybe I should in the future. Purpose of post was to give details to answer so that someone who might still be interested could benefit

Comment: Congratulations on YOUR answer and thanks for validating my input.